# How Can I Store Incorrect Answers In My Quiz and Repopulate Them In A Second Attempt

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have been working on a quiz program in C# for a few weeks now. I have it all pretty much working like it should except for one last detail. I want to be able to go through the quiz once, and then use any incorrect answers in a second attempt. At the end of both attempts I want to display a grade to the user. Any ideas how I would be able to do this? Here is a bit of my code that I am working with:

```
using System;

namespace Quiz
{
class MultipleChoiceQuiz
{
    public static void CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)
    {
        do
        {
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userAnswer != "A" && userAnswer != "B" && userAnswer != "C" && userAnswer != "D")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Not a Valid Input - Please Enter Valid Input");
            }
            else
            {
                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThat is correct!");
                    break;
                }
                else if (userAnswer != correctAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, that is incorrect.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
    public static void Questions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the HC-130J Power-On Quiz " + firstName + ".\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Using the keyboard, please submit answers by using the \'ENTER\' key.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please submit answers in CAPITAL letter form only.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to begin " + firstName + "? Hit the \'ENTER\' key now...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 1
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1 - What position does the ramp contol knob need to be in? " +
                          "\n\nA. 3N \nB. 1 \nC. 6N \nD. A or C \n\nWhat is your answer " + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("D");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 2
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 2 - After power is applied to the aircraft, the battery needs to be turned off? " +
                          "\n\nA. True \nB. False \n\nWhat is your answer " + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("A");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 3
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3 - Above what temperature does air condition need to be applied to the aircraft while power is applied? " +
                          "\n\nA. 75 degrees Fahrenheit \nB. 100 degrees Fahrenheit \nC. 95 degrees Fahrenheit \nD. 85 degrees Fahrenheit \n\nWhat is your answer " 
                          + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("C");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
```

I have one class and two methods. The one method is to evaluate the answers in the quiz as right or wrong. The other is to display all the questions and answers to the user. Any help anyone may be able to give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create member variables for storing the answers

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to keep track of the answers with an appropriate structure. One could use a dictionary, e.g:

```
Dictionary <string,string> questionsAndAnswers= new Dictionary <string,string>();
```

where key is your question and value is your answer. you could morever have a structure that holds the correctness of each answer. e.g:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string text {get;set;}
    public bool isCorrect {get;set;}
}
```

and have:

```
Dictionary <string,Answer> questionsAndAnswers= new Dictionary <string,Answer>();
```

Comment: That was my first thought... However on second look it seems like the player cant even give anything else then A,B,C,D:

`if (userAnswer != "A" && userAnswer != "B" && userAnswer != "C" && userAnswer != "D")`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to ask the questions again that the player answered incorrect?
Why not just add the question number to a list and then go thorugh that list again in the second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

An object-oriented approach to this problem would include a class that represents your question as well as a data structure to hold your user's answers. To associate the answers to the questions you'll need an identifier for each question. The code below will allow you to extend this application with many questions without copy/pasting a block of `Console.WriteLine`s. While that might seem faster (and to be fair I don't know your motivations here) it's always a good idea to consider extensibility and maintenance. A good object oriented structure will allow you to do more and write less code.

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Answers { get; set; }

    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<Question> _questions = new []
    {
        new Question
        {
            Id = 1,
            Text = "What position does the ramp contol knob need to be in?",
            Answers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {,
                { "A", "3N" },
                { "B", "1" },
                { "C", "6N" },
                { "D", "A or C" }
            },
            CorrectAnswer = "D"
        }
    };

    public static IDictionary<int, string> _answers = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the HC-130J Power-On Quiz " + firstName + ".\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Using the keyboard, please submit answers by using the \'ENTER\' key.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please submit answers in CAPITAL letter form only.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to begin " + firstName + "? Hit the \'ENTER\' key now...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        foreach(var question in _questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question.Text);
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach(var answer in question.Answers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}. {1}", answer.Key, answer.Value));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("What is your answer " + firstName + "?");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            while(!question.Answers.ContainsKey(response))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Not a Valid Input - Please Enter Valid Input");
                response = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if(response == question.CorrectAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThat is correct!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, that is incorrect.");
            }
            _answers[question.Id] = response;
        }

        // do whatever you want when the test is over
    }
}
```

A little more explanation: we create a `Question` class that has an identifier, some text (the actual question being asked), a collection of answers that are made up of a key (A, B, C, D, etc) and a value (the actual text of the answer), and a correct answer. We print out some initial, unique setup instructions in the form of asking the user for their name and giving them some prompts about how to take the test.

The real value here comes from the ability to loop over your well-defined objects. We print out the question test, then the answers (formatted so the user can understand them and choose appropriately), then ask the user for an answer, determine it's correctness, and store it.

Hope this helps!